# How to make an https request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing phonegap app, I want to access web service from server, in coding javascript get,post or ajax methods working fine for http url request but it cant work for **https** url request. 
Please help me, **how to called SOAP or secure web service to parse JSON in phonegap through javascript?**

Comment: for https it returning null but in borwser https url working fine,is there any flag in javascript for authentication token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same as every javascript(ajax) function do for phone-gap, in your case its just an invalid certificate issue as per the https server is concern.

Answer (score 9):

HTTPS is not another protocol, it is merely HTTP over an SSL/TLS-
encrypted connection. Since that encryption works transparent to the user agent, to perform a HTTPS AJAX call on your own domain name, your site must be using HTTPS, otherwise you are not able to selectively choose HTTPS on a page you want to perform an AJAX call on that isn't already using HTTPS.

So basically you can't call 'https://yourdomain.com/fetch' if the page you're calling the AJAX request from isn't using HTTPS.

If you want to perform an AJAX call to a HTTPS domain hosted somewhere else other than your domain, it is somewhat possible to do so (but only in Firefox 3.5+, Safari, Chrome and I think Opera), there is some interesting information about how to make cross-domain AJAX requests possible here: http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/ - this method is not supported in IE (no surprise there).

Comment: thank you Dwayne ,you right,but still i tried this using jquery.ajax and it returning null in success

Answer (score 0):

If the original loaded page is not connected via https:// then your Ajax calls will not work over https://.

Also Ajax calls must be on the same domain as the main site, as javascript does not allow cross domain Ajax connections.

Also ensure the server side function requested by the Ajax call is returning something other than null.